$v_t+\sin(v)v_x=0, v(0,x)=\alpha+\pi\sin(\pi x)$
Is it possible to obtain analytic solution of this equation? Using method of characteristics I get $v=\alpha+\pi\sin(\pi(x-t\sin(v)))$

I agree with your solution $v=\alpha+\pi\sin(\pi(x-t\sin(v)))$. This is the analytic solution on the form of implicit equation. So you have got the analytic solution. I suppose that you expect the analytic solution on explicit form. This mean solving the implicit equation for $v(x,t)$. I think that is not possible in terms on a finite number of standard functions.
